# How can I parse GeoJSON with Python

Tags: python, parsing, geojson

I have have geojson data from a query which I now want to parse and print on screen. My current code is:

```
import urllib
import geojson

while True:

    url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2012-01-01&endtime=2017-03-01&minmagnitude=4.0&maxmagnitude=9.0&minlongitude=5.95&maxlongitude=10.50&minlatitude=45.81&maxlatitude=47.81'
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print data
    break
```

It seems that `data` is a simple string. However, I thought it could be parsed like a `json` parameter. How do I have to handle `geojson` data in order to print a single `point`, e.g. to extract the coordinates of the first point only?

Comment: I guess the `while True` and the `break` can be removed completely?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can read it like any json:

```
import json
data = json.loads(datastring)
data['features'][0]['geometry'] #Your first point
```

Comment: if loading from a file: use data = json.load(fileobject)

Comment: This is what I am searching for. When I use your solution, I get a dict which looks like this `0  MultiLineString  [[[8.5551415, 49.8598025], [8.5563399, 49.8598...` with 3 columns. As you can see the third column has the coordinates I want. Do you know by any chances how I can transfer the coordinates into a dataframe with latitude and longitude as seperate colums since the values represent this?

Answer (score 54):

```
import geojson
with open(path_to_file) as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)
features = gj['features'][0]
```

Comment: How does this differ from loading the file with the base package `json`?

Comment: Works! Should be marked as the accepted answer!

Comment: The `geojson` library didn't have any releases since 2019, so I recommend to use more popular and recent `geopandas` instead

Comment: Has an error:  .load should be .loads

Comment: @lucidyan : version 3 was released in 2023

Answer (score 23):

You can also use `geopandas`:

```
import geopandas as gpd
earthquake = gpd.read_file('earthquake.geojson')
print(earthquake.head())
```

Comment: Caveat: this method is not reading data as geojson. It reads the data as geodataframe.

Comment: This is often the quickest and easiest way to read GeoJSON and make sense of what it contains.

Answer (score 6):

You can read it with json import, and file open:

```
import json
with open(path) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for feature in data['features']:
    print(feature['properties'])
```

Comment: I had to use utf-8 encoding: open(path, encoding='utf-8')

Answer (score 4):

You can use pandas library directly

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json('File.geojson')
```

The important this is to understand the structure of this json file and manipulate the dictionaries in there