# How to convert JSON data to PDF using python script

Tags: python, json, pdf

I want to convert JSON data to PDF which is getting from API.

example **JSON** data

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "state": "Manchester",
            "quantity": 20
        },
        {
            "state": "Surrey",
            "quantity": 46
        },
        {
            "state": "Scotland",
            "quantity": 36
        },
        {
            "state": "Kent",
            "quantity": 23
        },
        {
            "state": "Devon",
            "quantity": 43
        },
        {
            "state": "Glamorgan",
            "quantity": 43
        }
     ]   
}
```

I found this script: 
    http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578979-convert-json-to-pdf-with-python-and-xtopdf/

but getting **error**

> no module PDFWriter

Is there any another way to convert JSON Data PDF.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: seems that **xtopdf** is library or framework like that. this (https://jugad2.blogspot.com.tr/2012/07/guide-to-installing-and-using-xtopdf.html) explains how to install xtopdf may help you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413441/python-pdf-library

Answer (score 5):

the module PDFWriter is in `xtopdf`

> PDFWriter - a core class of the xtopdf toolkit - can now be used with
>   a Python context manager, a.k.a. the Python `with` statement.

( http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578790-use-pdfwriter-with-context-manager-support/ )

how to install `xtopdf` is in https://bitbucket.org/vasudevram/xtopdf :

> Installation and usage:
>
> To install the files, first make sure that you have downloaded and
>   installed all the prerequisities mentioned above, including setup
>   steps such as adding needed directories to your PYTHONPATH. Then, copy
>   all the files in xtopdf.zip into a directory which is on your
>   PYTHONPATH.
>
> To use any of the Python programs, run the .py file as:
>
> python filename.py
>
> This will give a usage message about the correct usage and arguments
>   expected.
>
> To run the shell script(s), do the same as above.
>
> Developers can look at the source code for further information.

an alternative  is to use `pdfdocument` to create the pdf, it can be installed using `pip` ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfdocument )

parse the data from the json data ( [How can I parse GeoJSON with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753745/how-can-i-parse-geojson-with-python), [Parse JSON in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/parse-json-in-python) ) and print it as pdf using  `pdfdocument` ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfdocument )

```
  import json
  data = json.loads(datastring)
```

---

```
from io import BytesIO
from pdfdocument.document import PDFDocument

def say_hello():
    f = BytesIO()
    pdf = PDFDocument(f)
    pdf.init_report()
    pdf.h1('Hello World')
    pdf.p('Creating PDFs made easy.')
    pdf.generate()
    return f.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from json2html import *
import json
import tempfile

class PdfConverter(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def to_html(self, json_doc):
        return json2html.convert(json=json_doc)

    def to_pdf(self, html_str):
        return pdfkit.from_string(html_str, None)

 def main():
     stowflw = {
     "data": [
        {
            "state": "Manchester",
            "quantity": 20
        },
       {
            "state": "Surrey",
            "quantity": 46
       },
       {
            "state": "Scotland",
            "quantity": 36
       },
       {
            "state": "Kent",
            "quantity": 23
       },
       {
             "state": "Devon",
             "quantity": 43
       },
       {
             "state": "Glamorgan",
             "quantity": 43
       }
     ]
   }

    pdfc = PdfConverter()
    with open("sample.pdf", "wb") as pdf_fl:
       pdf_fl.write(pdfc.to_pdf(pdfc.to_html(json.dumps(stowflw))))
```

1. install json2html
2. install pdfkit (requires wkhtmltox)

Answer (score 0):

**when you hit this code it will generate a pdf for this url (API).**

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('https://api.covid19api.com/summary', 'india.pdf')
```

**you can also generate an pdf from a different formats like .file, .html ,  .text, multiple url**

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get('https://api.covid19api.com/summary').text

 # loads converts a string to a JSON object
json_object = json.loads(response) 

# json. dumps converts a json object to a string
print(json.dumps(json_object, indent=1))
```

```
#different formats 
pdfkit.from_url('http://aj7t.me', 'output.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'output.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'output.pdf')
```

For more information,
 [please check the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/)!