# Finding location using .geojson file using python

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

I have a `map.geojson` file that contains the regional boundaries of a various cities.

How can I calculate the region of a point given by (latitude, longitude)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can parse the geojson and extract the points / coordinates

```
 import json 
 data = json.loads(datastring)
 data['features'][0]['geometry'] #Your first point
```

( [How can I parse GeoJSON with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753745/how-can-i-parse-geojson-with-python) )

> When you load a GeoJSON file using the json library, you get a dict
>   that contains an entry features, which contains the list of features.
>   Each feature in turn consists of a dict, which, among other things,
>   contains an entry geometry. The geometry is a dict containing the
>   entries type and coordinates. So you can traverse your GeoJSON file
>   like this:

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for feature in data['features']:
    print feature['geometry']['type']
    print feature['geometry']['coordinates']
```

( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73768/how-to-convert-geojson-to-python-objects )

now that you have the coordinates / points create a **polygon** in shapely with it to get a geometric representation of the city boundaries : [How to create a Polygon given its Point vertices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457089/how-to-create-a-polygon-given-its-point-vertices)

> Point-in-Polygon
>
> Now that you have a polygon, determining whether a point is inside it
>   is very easy. There’s 2 ways to do it.
>
> ```
> `point.within(polygon)`
> `polygon.contains(point)`
> ```
>
> **point should be an instance of the Point class**, and poly is of course
>   an instance of Polygon. within and contains are the converse of each
>   other, so whichever method you use is entirely up to you.

https://streamhacker.com/2010/03/23/python-point-in-polygon-shapely/

in shapely is a specific class to handle points and only points that are represented in this class will work in the `point.within(polygon)`
and  `polygon.contains(point)` functions.

> **The point type is implemented by a Point class**; curve by the
>   LineString and LinearRing classes; and surface by a Polygon class.
>   Shapely implements no smooth (i.e. having continuous tangents) curves.
>   All curves must be approximated by linear splines. All rounded patches
>   must be approximated by regions bounded by linear splines.

( https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html )

so you have to take your decimal `lat`, `lon` values and insert them in the shapely point class :

```
 from shapely.geometry import Point
 point = Point(0.0, 0.0)
 q = Point((0.0, 0.0))
```

( https://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#points )

with this `point.within(polygon)` and  `polygon.contains(point)` functions will work ...

Comment: So, I was able to figure out this part. But, I am not able to point the region to which the point location. I have tried `Point.within(Polygon)` and `Polygon.contains(Point)`. They are not working. By the way, user input is a set of two decimal points`(lat, lan)`.