# Using plotly i want to plot choropleth map for Indian districts

Tags: pandas, plotly, geopandas, choropleth

Using plotly i want to plot choropleth map for Indian districts. I am able to do it for Indian states. The link for Indian geojson states is - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbrobst/56c13bbbf9d97d187fea01ca62ea5112/raw/e388c4cae20aa53cb5090210a42ebb9b765c0a36/india_states.geojson

And link for Indian geojson districts is https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/adityaradha007/indian-districts-geojson.

This is my df:

```
df = {
    'district': ['Thiruvananthapuram', 'Kasaragod', 'Malappuram', 'Pathanamthitta', 'Wayanad', 'Alappuzha', 'Kozhikode',
                 'Kollam', 'Thrissur', 'Palakkad', 'Kannur', 'Kottayam', 'Ernakulam', 'Idukki'],
    'registeredUsers': [989791, 294943, 871127, 271165, 234308, 534116, 887215, 623472, 768604, 620428, 640842, 504349,
                        1454447, 277492],
    'appOpens': [5574116, 5220451, 9688261, 4036616, 6349929, 2971951, 8824744, 4995465, 5764628, 9057055, 8394165,
                 4454903, 8812130, 9903479]
}
```

below code works for state:

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jbrobst/56c13bbbf9d97d187fea01ca62ea5112/raw/e388c4cae20aa53cb5090210a42ebb9b765c0a36/india_states.geojson",
    featureidkey='properties.ST_NM',
    locations='state',
    color='registeredUsers',
    color_continuous_scale="viridis_r"
    #scope="asia",
    #range_color = (0, 12),
    #color_continuous_scale='Blues'
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}) #scale map
fig.show()
```

below code does not work for districts:

```
fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson="/Users/adityaradhakrishnan/Desktop/output.geojson",
    featureidkey='properties.dtname',
    locations='district',
    color='registeredUsers',
    color_continuous_scale="viridis_r"
    #scope="asia",
    #range_color = (0, 12),
    #color_continuous_scale='Blues'
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}) #scale map
fig.show()
```

but using matplotlib im able to plot(please not i am trying to plot only partial map here):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd

# Read GeoJSON data into a GeoDataFrame
gdf = gpd.read_file("/Users/adityaradhakrishnan/Desktop/output.geojson")

# Merge the GeoDataFrame with your DataFrame based on the 'district' column
merged = gdf.merge(df, left_on='dtname', right_on='district')

# Plot the choropleth map
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
merged.plot(column='registeredUsers', cmap='viridis_r', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8', legend=True)

# Set plot title and axis labels
ax.set_title('Registered Users by District')
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried your code out. On Firefox I got a clear error in the console:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///my-path/output.geojson. (Reason: CORS request not http).

[MDN says this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp?utm_source=devtools&utm_medium=firefox-cors-errors&utm_campaign=default):

> Local files from the same directory and subdirectories were historically treated as being from the same origin. This meant that a file and all its resources could be loaded from a local directory or subdirectory during testing, without triggering a CORS error.
>
> Unfortunately this had security implications, as noted in this advisory: CVE-2019-11730. Many browsers, including Firefox and Chrome, now treat all local files as having opaque origins (by default). As a result, loading a local file with included local resources will now result in CORS errors.
>
> Developers who need to perform local testing should now set up a local server. As all files are served from the same scheme and domain (localhost) they all have the same origin, and do not trigger cross-origin errors.

In this case we don't need to set up a local server. We can just read the local file, parse it and pass the result to `geojson`. After this the map displays.

With the data set you linked the map doesn't show all districts, I'm not sure why this is. I found another data set for Indian districts and that one seems to work (https://github.com/geohacker/india/blob/master/district/india_district.geojson):

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import geojson

with open('india_district.geojson') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

df = {
    'district': ['Thiruvananthapuram', 'Kasaragod', 'Malappuram', 'Pathanamthitta', 'Wayanad', 'Alappuzha', 'Kozhikode', 'Kollam', 'Thrissur', 'Palakkad', 'Kannur', 'Kottayam', 'Ernakulam'],
    'registeredUsers': [989791, 294943, 871127, 271165, 234308, 534116, 887215, 623472, 768604, 620428, 640842, 504349, 1454447],
    'appOpens': [5574116, 5220451, 9688261, 4036616, 6349929, 2971951, 8824744, 4995465, 5764628, 9057055, 8394165, 4454903, 8812130]
}

fig = px.choropleth(
    df,
    geojson=gj,
    featureidkey='properties.NAME_2',
    locations='district',
    color='registeredUsers',
    color_continuous_scale="viridis_r"
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=False)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}) #scale map
fig.show()
```

Parsing code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47792385/9098350).

Comment: This is plotting the map. but its not correct. Its just plotting one district Idukki. The rest is yellow in color.

Comment: Not sure why that happens. Maybe the geojson data set is not good. I got it working with above approach with a different data set. Downloaded this one https://github.com/geohacker/india/blob/master/district/india_district.geojson. Instead of `'properties.dtname` use `'properties.NAME_2'`.